# What are some names, colloquial or otherwise, for the "Thirty Years War" in German?

Tags: terminology

What would Germans call what the English call the Thirty Years War — both formally and informally?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This would translate almost literally in

[Dreißigjähriger Krieg](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drei%C3%9Figj%C3%A4hriger_Krieg)

that is used both colloquial, and in a formal setting. However some historians scientifically disagree with this term.

Comment: it's still the only word I know, both formally and informally. +1

Comment: Why do some historians disagree on the name?

Comment: @Tim N: as far as I understood (I'm no historian) the notion that it was only one war is historically incorrect. There were several different wars as in this 30 years period of time.